# C++ new instance of nested class

Tags: c++, nested

Here is my code

```
template <typename T>
struct Item
{
    T* Product;
    Item *next;

    Item(T*);
};

template <typename T>
Item<T>::Item(T *prod)
{
    this->Product = prod;
    this->next = nullptr;
}

template <typename T>
class Catalog
{
private:
    Item<T> *first;
    Item<T> *last;
    unsigned int count;
public:
    struct Item;  //i need Item as nested structure

    void Add(T*);
};

template <typename T>
void Catalog<T>::Add(T *ptr)
{
    //only for simplification, algorithm I already have

    this->first = new Item<T>(ptr);
    //or
    this->last = new Item<T>(ptr);

}
```

I do not know how add new Item to my class Catalog. If Item is not nested struct, I can use simply `new Item<T>(ptr)`

Is any way how to do this?? It is my project to school and I need Item as nested struct.

Thank you, sorry about my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring two different `Item`.  The
first is a non-nested template struct, which you (probably)
don't want to use, and the second is an incomplete nessted
struct.  The second is the one you probably want to use, *but*
it is incomplete, so you cannot create an instance of it.  What
you should do is put the entire definition of the `Item` in the
class `Catalog`, instead of just the forward definition.  (And
don't define it there as a template: the type you want is
`Catalog<T>::Item`, and not `Catalog<T>:Item<U>`.)  Then, of
course, inside the class template, it is `new Item` (and not `new
Item<T>`); outside the class, it is `new Catalog<T>::Item`.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the definition inside the definition of the class:

```
template <typename T>
class Catalog
{
public:

    struct Item
    {
       T* Product;
       Item *next;

       Item(T*);
    };

    void Add(T*);

private:
    Item *first;
    Item *last;
    unsigned int count;
};
```

Note that now the struct's type is `Catalog<T>::Item`, so elsewhere you will have to use that instead of just `Item<T>`:

```
template <typename T>
Catalog<T>::Item::Item(T *prod)
{
    this->Product = prod;
    this->next = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile this?  `Item` isn't a template, so `Item<T>` is illegal.

Comment: Obviously not. Forgot to change that.